# FCM Message delivery report is not received

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp, smack

I use an Application Server to send downstream message to android device via FCM using XMPP.
As mentioned in docmentation, I set "delivery_receipt_requested" to true, but most of the times I am not receiving delivery request report from device. I just receive ACK messages from FCM which confirms that Data Message is delivered to FCM Server (but not received by the target android device).

Is there any way from experts to help me?

Comment: Is there any Answer or tip from experts?

Comment: The question is fairly unclear and doesn't include any code or Firebase structures to help us understand what you are asking. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why you use FCM? It must used only for those users is currently in `unavailable` state to be notified of new message with short preview. What's your xmpp server?

Comment: @Mahdi: Hi Mahdi, I use FCM to Push Messages with Data Payload to connected android devices. In fact after some state of art search I find it a good way to Push Messages to android clients (not mobile phones but android displays/monitors) to show some advertisement content.
For XMPP server I access Google CCS Endpoint.

Comment: @Mahdi: do you have some remarks regarding the use of FCM to Push data content to android devices?